# How to remove leading YYYY-MM-DD and format the data type in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am trying to format the column to data type "duration" in PowerBI. In order to do this, I need to remove the YYYY-MM-DD which appeared after the data load. Im guessing that the inconsistencies are due to some values being in this format: -3:34 and orders in this: 10:43:00

This is how the column looks in powerbi:
[image: image1]

This is how it looks in Excel before the import to powerbi:
[image: image2]

I have tried to "replace values" in powerquery, which gives me this result:

[image: image 3]

Once I change the datatype to "duration" and "apply and load" it gives me this result:

[image: image4]

I am expecting the result to be -02:03, 03:01. Negative values indicate an early delivery and positive values indicate a late delivery. e.g. 2h 3 min early or 3h 1 min late. Column needs to be in some form of time data type since I am planning to do calculations etc.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Some form of `table.replace()`? I tried `table.replace` but got errors. the dax function **Substitute** works but I want to be able to delete one of the columns since the substitute will give me a new column.

Comment: What is the data column type in your excel? text?

Comment: No, its time. But once its imported in pbi it becomes text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a test with a column in Excel (which is time). I imported in Power-Bi using the following query language (Please note the type duration in last step):

```
    let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\...\Test.xlsx"), null, true),
Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"HHMM_DELAYED", type duration}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Seconds", each Duration.TotalSeconds([HHMM_DELAYED]), type number),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "DurationText", each Duration.ToText([HHMM_DELAYED]))
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

This worked perfecly fine for me, see result below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will try this, but I have never imported through code before. Where do i do that in power bi?

Comment: under advanced Editor (Desktop version)

Comment: I noticed that the column is in "general" in excel. Cant seem to convert it to time without getting different type of errors. I have tried to use the 1904 date system and divide the values by 24 before converting it to time. All my negative whole numbers (-24) become -00:00. Do you know if your code works on the column if its in "general" or "text". I will try it as soon I get the chanse today.

Comment: It does not matter what type it is coming from. I asked the question just to ensure I had same scenario as you had. I tested it now with "general" is works. This seems logic because it converts the text to a duration.

Comment: THANK YOU, IT WORKED! I got errors on all my positive numbers because of the leading YY-MM-DD (once again). I changed the column back to text, removed the leading year-month-date and reversed it back to duration.

Comment: You are welcome, please vote on answer and mark as answered.

Comment: I thought it worked, please se my post below. Would be forever grateful if you might be able to help me :) @Aldert